# How to remove the text between the quotation marks?

Tags: r, text

Here is my data:

```
x <- 'aaaaa,"bbb",ccccc,"dddd",abcd"dddd"'
```

How to remove: `"bbb"`,`"dddd"` and `"dddd"`

So I can get:

```
"aaaaa","ccccc","abcd"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `gsub` to match the pattern of double quote (`"`) followed by one or more characters that are not a double quote (`[^"]+`) followed by a double quote (`"`) and a `,` if present and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub('"[^"]+",?', "", txt)
[1] "aaaaa,ccccc,abcd"
```

If we need to keep the `,` in between

```
gsub('"[^"]+"', "", txt)
[1] "aaaaa,,ccccc,,abcd"
```

#### data

```
txt <- 'aaaaa,"bbb",ccccc,"dddd",abcd"dddd"'
```

Comment: Why I get:  c(     ) as the result?

Comment: @Foulball not clear what you meant by that

Comment: there are lots of blank lines in the parentheses.

Comment: @Foulball No idea regarding that.  I used your input and showed the expected output

Comment: DFA$ContentNoQuotes <- gsub('"[^"]+",?', "", DFA)

Comment: head(DFA$ContentNoQuotes)
[1] "c(              \n              \n              \n              \n            )"

Comment: @Foulball Assuming `DFA` is a data.frame.  `gsub` works on vectors or columns of dataset and not on the whole `data.frame`

Comment: @Foulball i.e. if you are intereested in applying the `gsub` on all the columns (more than one colun of dataset), use lapply i.e. `DFA[] <- lapply(DFA, function(x) gsub('"[^"]+"', "", x))` and if it is only a single column, extract the column as a vector i.e. `DFA$ContentNoQuotes <- gsub('"[^"]+"', "", DFA$Content)`

Comment: I think it is something wrong with my real data. They are news articles. It works for some articles, but does not work for some articles as well.

Comment: @Foulball as i said, if it is a data.frame, then `gsub` doesn't expect it.  It should be a vector or single column of the dataset.  Pleaes check my previous comment as to what you need

Comment: DFA is a data.frame, I see where is wrong:
DFA$ContentNoQuotes <- gsub('"[^"]+",?', "", DFA$Content)

This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the words with double quotes in them.

```
gsub('"\\w+",?', '', x)
#[1] "aaaaa,ccccc,abcd"
```

If you want them as vector of words -

```
strsplit(gsub('"\\w+",?', '', x), ',')[[1]]
#[1] "aaaaa" "ccccc" "abcd"
```